# JSF2.2, RequestScope and component persistence

Tags: viewstate, jsf-2.2, myfaces, mojarra

My actual scenario is a simple JSF project that uses **Mojarra 2.2.5**.
I'm trying to get programmatically a component instance (via "findComponent" method or binding ...) and set some attributes (click on "*ChangeColor*" button).
After that, using any other action (for example clicking on "*Send*" button), the previous changes are ignored !!
It seems that changeColor method don't update the ViewState !
The sample code is the following:

```xhtml
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:inputText id="input" binding="#{page9.input}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Change BackColor" action="#{page9.changeColor}"/>           
        <h:commandButton value="Send" action="#{page9.dummy}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And the relative **RequestScope** bean

```java
@ManagedBean(name="page9")
@RequestScoped
public class Page9 implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private HtmlInputText input;

public HtmlInputText getInput() {
    return input;
}
public void setInput(HtmlInputText input) {
    this.input = input;
}

public void changeColor(){      
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HtmlInputText hit = (HtmlInputText) fc.getViewRoot().findComponent(":form:input");
    hit.setStyle("background-color:blue");
}


public void dummy(){

}

}
```

Some important considerations:
1) I must use RequestScope for compatibility reasons.
2) Setting javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to "false" all works fine (!).
3) Trying to use **MyFaces** 2.2.3 libraries all works fine (!).

What do you think about ?
Thanks.

Comment: I've just tried with Mojarra 2.2.8, with the same results !! :-(

Comment: I've just tried with Mojarra 2.2.10, with the same results !! :-(

Comment: This https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3875 was closed. It will be available in 2.3.0.